# What alpha value should I compare against in the problem below? Also, what would be the population that the answer could be generalized to?

Tags: statistics

complete a test of significance for the following situation. An association of college bookstores reported that the average amount of money spent by students on textbooks was 325.16 with a standard deviation of 76.42. A random sample of 75 students at the local college campus indicated that an average bill for textbooks for the semester in question to be 312.34. (Wouldn't this be a convenience sample and possibly interfere with the answer?) Do these data provide significant evidence at a 95% confidence level that the actual bill is different from the 325.16 that was reported?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Comments:

- "A *random* sample of 75 students at a local college campus...," if truly taken at random would not be a 'convenience sample' and statistical inferences should be valid
  for students at that campus.
- Strictly speaking, the terminology '95% confidence level' should refer to a confidence interval, not to a test of hypothesis. However, if you do a two-sided
  test of $H_0: \mu = 325.16$ against $H_a: \mu \ne 325.16$, you will fail to reject $H_0$ at the 5% level precisely when a 95% CI for $\mu$ based on $n = 75, \bar X = 312.34,$ and $\sigma = 76.42$ includes the 'null value'
  $\mu_0 = 325.16.$
- It seems to me that you are supposed to take the
  results of the *college bookstore survey* as being exact (presumably based on a huge sample and so with negligible sampling error). By contrast, it seems you are to consider the *local campus data* to be subject to
  sampling error because it is based on only 75 students. I think it is a flaw in the problem as stated not to make these assumptions clear.

The 95% CI for the *local college* is of the form $\bar X \pm 1.96\sigma/\sqrt{n}.$ That is $312.34 \pm 1.96(76.42/\sqrt{75})$ or
$(295.0445, 329.6355).$

For the hypothesis test *at the local college,* the test statistic is
$$Z = \frac{\bar X - \mu_0}{\sigma/\sqrt{75}}= \frac{312.34 - 326.16}{76.42/\sqrt{75}},$$
and you would reject $H_0$ at level 5% if $|Z| > 1.96.$